# Babel obfuscation causing Norton to treat exe as threat

Tags: c#, android

I'm using a trial version of Babel to obfuscate the primary output of a WinForm app which is an exe file and when I run the Babel console Norton catches the exe file as a threat saying SAPE.Heur.9C6D7. I've tried changing all the settings in Babel and nothing seems to work. However when I run Babel as a post build event to create an Android dll it runs fine. Has anyone come across this problem/know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is no fix for this issue.